# Eclipse Build does not generate WAR

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a **Maven WEB Project** that I am having problems **configuring**. I am trying to get the project to build a `WAR` and place it in the target directory when I build through `Eclipse`, but when I do a `build`, nothing appears to be happening. Is there anything special that I have to do to setup what happens when I do a `build` through `Eclipse`?

Right now, when I build, the `target directory` gets created and a `m2e-wtp` folder gets generated, not sure what that is.

Comment: which cmd you use to create build in mvn ??

Comment: can you check builders which are currently configured on that project. It should have maven builder configured

Comment: What does the POM file say?  Does it say `<packaging>war</packaging>`?

Answer (score 0):

Executing `mvn clean install` command from the directory where `pom.xml` is present will generate the WAR file. Sometimes IDE fails to reload the application target folder after external build. Try to refresh the workspace in Eclipse after building the application.

You can also try `mvn clean install -X` to run the build process in debug mode. This way you can figure out the exact problem.

Shishir